# cross domain CORS support for backbone.js

Tags: ajax, node.js, backbone.js, express, cors

I'm trying to implement a cross-domain setup for my backbone app.

my server (express.js) is allowing cross domains and credential:

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  var allowedHost = [
    'http://localhost:3001',
    'http://localhost:7357'
  ];

  if(allowedHost.indexOf(req.headers.origin) !== -1) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin)
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version');
    next();
  } else {
    res.send({auth: false});
  }
}

app.configure(function(){
    ....
    app.use(allowCrossDomain);
    ....
});
```

my client (backbone.js) is configured to accept cross domain as well :

```
define(["backbone", "jquery", "underscore"], function (BB, $, _) {
  return BB.Model.extend({

    idAttribute: "_id",

    initialize: function () {
      var that = this;

      $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
        options.crossDomain ={
          crossDomain: true
        };
        options.xhrFields = {
          withCredentials: true
        };
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Now when I test my code (let say a `POST` request), i have a very special behavior:

```
var contacts = new Contacts;
contacts.create({'name': 'my name'});
```

The browser return this message:

> OPTIONS ... 404 (Not Found)
>   jquery.js:8419

This totally confuse me as the `OPTIONS` http method is not supported by backbone?

Comment: The OPTIONS call is the preflight request: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely, your Express routes only specify `GET` and/or `POST` methods.  For example,

```
app.post('/some/api/method', function(req, res) { ... });
```

This means you've only defined a route handler for `POST`s to */some/api/method*, and requests using any other method (like `GET` or `OPTIONS`) will return a 404.

In certains cituations (such as sending custom HTTP headers), XHR requests to a cross-origin URL using [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) requires that the browser must first issue an `OPTIONS` request to see if cross domain requests are allowed.  Only if the `OPTIONS` request succeeds (HTTP 200 **with** CORS headers) will the browser make the actual request.

Since you've only defined a `POST` route on your server, the `OPTIONS` request fails and the browser doesn't make the request.  You need to properly respond to the `OPTIONS` request:

```
app.options('/some/api/method', function(req, res) {
    // At this point, the `allowCrossDomain()` middleware will already have
    // taken care of the CORS stuff, so just return OK.
    res.send(200);
});
```

Now, the preflight `OPTIONS` check will pass, so the real request to the `POST` handler will be made.

---

Bonus comments regarding your code:

- Performance improvements:

  - Use an object to lookup and validate origins rather than an array.  Using `indexOf` requires slow iteration of the array on every request, where using an object allows quick lookup.  (Remember that JavaScript objects store their keys in a dictionary-like data structure.)
  - Define `allowedHosts` *outside* the validation function – they don't change, so there's no need to create a new object each time `allowCrossDomain` is invoked (requiring garbage collection).
- You should probably send a non-success HTTP response code when the cross-origin check fails.

```
var allowedHost = {
  'http://localhost:3001': true,
  'http://localhost:7357': true
};

var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  if(allowedHost[req.headers.origin]) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin)
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version');
    next();
  } else {
    res.send(403, {auth: false});
  }
}
```