# Backbone.js approach

Tags: backbone.js

I have a form (on localhost) with 2 fields:

First Name (text box)
Last Name (text box)

Once the form is submitted, I need to use API - https://beta.test.com/api

The documentation says -

"POST /user will add the details to system and generates a user ID which would be returned."

After I receive user ID in response, I need to call another endpoint -

"POST /user/metadata will fetch the metadata for a previously added user."

I have to build this in backbonejs. What should be my approach? Do you have any tutorials which I can look at?

I did some code but it gave me - "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". I have checked on server and the API already has cross domain allowed for all.

Please suggest.

Comment: you have to enable `beta.test.com` to allow cross-origin requests. http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Answer (score 0):

For a good example look at [TODO app in backbone way](http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html).

I will also suggest you to read [Backbone's documentation](http://backbonejs.org/) and view the source code.
It will documented so you can find all you need there, if no look into the [source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html).

---

**Simple implementation of your form could be achieved like this:**

For interaction with API and data exchange via REST create User model:

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'your/api/path',
    default: { // this will be setted when model attributes are empty
        firstname: 'Default Name', 
        lastname: 'Default Lastname'  
    }
});
```

Form view which will render you form and will bind model's attributes to the form's elements:

```
var UserForm = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    el: '.form-container', // this will attach view to the DOM's element with 'form-container' class
    template: _.template($('#user-form').html()),
    events: {
       'submit': 'onFormSubmitted',
       // validation logic could be added here
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    },
    onFormSubmitted: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // we don't need to submit the form
        // get form elements here and setting on model
        // saving model at the end
        var firstName = this.$('input[name="firstname"]').val();
        var lastName = this.$('input[name="lastName"]').val();

        this.model.set({firstname: firstName, lastname: lastName});
        this.model.save(); // this will make POST request to your API
     }
});
```

And then initialize you view and pass User model.

```
var userForm = new UserForm({model: new UserModel()});
```

I have left the declaration of template for you.

---

There is a lot of staff for cross origin requests policy issues when using Backbone. Actually it's not the Backbone thing. Backbone uses `$.ajax` to interact with REST-full resources. So you just need to configure `$.ajax`. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041172/backbone-js-wont-make-cross-host-requests).

Comment: This helps. How about using the next endpoint? Should I add another model for it?

Comment: The endpoints are - https://beta.test.com/api/user & https://beta.test.com/api/user/metadata. We have more endpoints like - https://beta.test.com/api/group, https://beta.test.com/api/group/metadata. Would be nice to set it up once and forget it.

Comment: Do you have any tutorials which I can also look at? Any github examples which are already built?

Comment: There is a lot of examples online. I have also published useful staff [here](http://itnews.sourcio.com/author/vahan). Can you provide real example ? It's possible to save to different endpoints for one model, but you need to rewrite the `save` method of Backbone.Model.

Comment: How do I fix the cross domain issue using $.ajax

Comment: You need to configure `$.ajax`'s options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66631/discussion-between-dang-and-vahan-vardanyan).